# Algorithm to Fit Intuitively Important Data Points

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, approximation

It is hard to formalize what I am asking without knowing the answer, but in experimental mathematics it is very common to see a graph of points hinting at limiting behavior. The graph below makes me think there could exist a nice upper function for sufficiently large n, where the least upper function is not monotonic. The "nice" points that would be most helpful to approximate a least upper function is highlighted in blue in the second picture. Is there a well recognized machine learning algorithm that does this? How does such a method formalize intuition?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a much smarter way to do this. But this was my first thought, and it works pretty well. I started by simulating some data for $X \in (0,1)$. 
$$Y = \exp(1\cdot X) + 3 + \epsilon$$
Where $\epsilon \sim N(0, .3\cdot X)$, to create a heteroskedastic model. The data looks like this.[image]

Instead of using regular least squares, we need to penalize a model for being below the data points. That is, we minimize
$$\omega(y - \hat y) + (1-\omega)(y-\hat y)^2$$

Where $\hat Y = \exp(\theta_1 X) + \theta_2$.

Where $\omega \in (0,1)$ controls the penalty. Using a weighted minimization, using $X$ as the weights and (manually) choosing $\omega = 0.6$, gives the following.
[image]

Comment: The word "heteroskedastic" has changed my life. I am going to do some background and wait a bit before accepting.